# Why is my program printing out more times than expected?

Tags: c, strcmp

I have a program that reads in a file, goes through line by line, and breaks up the line word by word. My problem is, I am about to store each word in a array but I need to use `strcmp` function to verify the word doesnt already exist. Anyways below is my code and my question is, why is my program printing out `1` so many times? I was expecting it to only print it out twice because `this` occurs twice in my text file.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fi) != NULL) { // looping through each line

    line_count += 1;

    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(line); j++) { // convert all words to lowercase
        line[j] = tolower(line[j]);
    }

    result = strtok(line, delimiters);

    while (result != NULL) {
        word_count += 1;

        if (strcmp(result, "this")) {
            printf("1\n");
        }

        result = strtok(NULL, delimiters); // get the next token
    }
}
```

Below is my text file:

```
This is the first test.
This is the second test.
```

Comment: `strcmp(result, "this") == 0` is what you want.

Comment: You have the conditon wrong.  It prints 1 for each time the string does not match.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns `0` if the string matches. You're checking for a truthy value. You really want `strcmp(result, "this") == 0`.

You will also need to make the match case insensitive, which is usually called `stricmp()`.

Answer (score -1):

Do you try again after change "strcmp(result, "this")" to "strcmp(result, "This")" ?